# How to pause and resume a Java application that writes on a text file

Tags: java

I have a little program which writes the current date and the current time into a text file. However, it continues write until I close the frame. So I added a pause button to it and wish to pause and resume the program instead of have to close and start it again (if is that makes sense).

So is there anyway that I can achieve this?

Many thanks in advance!!!

please see the code below

```
class RecordTask extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("breaths.txt", true)));
            out.println(new Date().toString());
            out.close();
            Breaths++;
            lblB.setText("Breaths: " + Breaths);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), e.toString(), "",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    // Check if Start button is pressed
    if (event.getSource() == startButton) {
        int value = (int) txtRate.getValue();

        timer = new Timer();
        int interval = (int)((((double) 60) / (double) value) * 1000);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RecordTask(), interval, interval);

        startButton.setEnabled(false);
    } else // Check if pause button pressed
    if (event.getSource() == pauseButton) {
        //Pause the breaths
    } else // Check if exit button pressed
    if (event.getSource() == exitButton) {
        // close the program
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

So I basically need to pause the function and resume it. :)

Comment: You could call `cancel` on the `RecordTask` or `cancel` on the `Timer`.  In either case, you'd need to re-create either the `RecordTask` or `Timer` (depending on which you canceled)

Comment: hum, ok but how do I cancel it? ... sorry for the ...  question is coz I'm completely new to programming. Do you mean on the actionevent ?

Comment: There's a `cancel` method on both classes.  In your case, since you don't maintain a reference to the `RecordTask`, you will probably need to use `Timer#cancel`

Comment: Ok so the cancel method is the only way to stop it? sorry man I keep on going...

Comment: It would seem to be a reasonable solution.  You can't really "pause", you can just start and stop

Comment: humm, ok I got you... thanks for that, but im still lost in how to use the cancel method...

Comment: Like any method, simply call it on the instance of `Timer` you have, `timer.cancel()`.  Depending on your setup you might consider setting the reference `null` as well, so when you want to restart it, you could check to see if the current instance is `null` or not.  If `null`, create a new `Timer`, otherwise, do nothing (as it's only `null` when after you cancel it)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `java.util.Timer` use `javax.swing.Timer`. It has methods `start()`, `stop()`. Moreover, `java.util.Timer` is not safe regarding Swing API because schedules tasks in a thread other than EDT and you use in your task `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`.